# MySQL Join with COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, join, count

i think today is not my day - sorry, but i have another COUNT(*) question:

I have this easy query:

```
SELECT * FROM domains 
LEFT JOIN subpages ON subpages.domainid = domains.id 
WHERE domains.id = 293 
AND subpages.seitenart = 'Startseite'
```

It works perfect but i need additionally a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM subpages WHERE subpages.statussub = '1' AND subpages.domainid = 293
```

Okay, for a better understanding:
I have the table "domains" and the table "subpages". Now i want to display the Domaindetails of one Domain where i need the domain table and subpages table with field subpages.seitenart = "Startseite".

Additionally i have to count all subpages in the subpages table where subpages.statussub = '1'

Hope this is better explained!

Can anyone help pls?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: Can't you put the second select as a select in your first query?

Comment: What do you mean by "need additionally"? Just run the query additionally :)

Comment: I would suggest to have that count query as separate select rather than doing some sql trick to combine those 2 queries into one.

Comment: @SiteSafeNL - okay, i will try

Comment: @anubhava: this is not the professional way...

Comment: @codeworxx: lol... could you explain why it is not 'professional'? And what exactly 'professional' means?

Comment: Given that you use `select *`, I think the "professional" boat has sailed for you...

Comment: @blindy: i need almost all fields of that table so why not use select * ???
@Mchl: it means that if you can combine the query's, you should do. making 2 querys is not an elegant way...

Comment: @codeworxx: I'm bit surprised that you took my simple suggestion "unprofessional". It was not an answer just a comment, you can very well ignore my suggestion and go your happy way. However the **ONLY** reason why I suggested 2 queries because earlier you didn't have `seitenart = "Startseite"` in your **count** query and the fact Jon could provide you single query only after you decided to alter your original question.

Comment: @anubhava - that's wrong! The "subpages.seitenart = 'Startseite'" was always in my question and jon understood and has written the answer BEFORE i changed ANYTHING in my question! i'm sorry, that you feel offended - that was not my purpose!

Comment: Well in that case count() in Jon's answer does not seem correct to me since your select count query is: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM subpages WHERE subpages.statussub = '1' AND subpages.domainid = 293` which is **WITHOUT** `seitenart = 'Startseite'` condition and the answer you accepted has this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to limit the COUNT to seitenart = 'Startseite' try:

```
SELECT domains.*, COUNT(s1.<column_name>) as total
FROM subpages s1, domains LEFT JOIN subpages s2 ON s2.domainid = domains.id
WHERE domains.id = 293
AND s2.seitenart = 'Startseite'
AND s1.statussub = '1'
AND s1.domainid = domains.id
```

Comment: you're right, i dont want to limit count to seitenart="Startseite" but with your query i get an error, that "unknown column s1 in field list" - if i change count(s1) to count(s1.*) then i need a group by?!?! any help?

Comment: I got it wrong - I don't think you can use s1.* inside the COUNT() function. Try using s1.subpage_id or whatever unique ID you have on the subpages table.